# Tomcat 400 Bad Request: How to accept < (less than sign) on URI?

Tags: tomcat

When I send this request to Tomcat it is working

```
http://example.org/?foo=%3Cbar/%3E
```

But this one gives "**400 Bad Request**"

```
http://example.org/?foo=<bar/>
```

I do know that the request is malformed and the the client side behave properly but they don't. They don't follow the RFC standard but I can't change that. I have to deal with it.

Is it possible to force Tomcat to accept this malformed request anyway?

Answer (score 2):

A solution is to add `relaxedQueryChars` to the `Connector` in `server.xml` so the **unsafe** characters are accepted:

```
<Connector relaxedQueryChars='&lt;&gt;' ... />
```

As '<' is used in server.xml as special characters the ampersand encoding &lt; has to be used.

The solution was found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361171/how-to-allow-character-in-urls-for-tomcat-8-5

Further information about the `relaxedQueryChars` limitations:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#Standard_Implementation